# Exception error while using fun hd/1 in erlang

Tags: erlang

I did the following in order to get each list's head:

```
lists:map(fun hd/1, [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).
```

The result is:

```
** exception error: undefined function erl_eval:hd/1
```

But when used otherwise:

```
lists:map(fun(A) -> hd(A) end, [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).
```

I got appropriate result! Sorry for trivial question but can you tell me why it is not working with `fun hd/1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fun erlang:hd/1` as the syntax. You need the module name here for that `fun` syntax to work.

Comment: Thank you it worked! But can you tell why in erlang shell I'm suppose to add 'erlang:' while in the created module it's not necessary?

Comment: The Erlang shell uses erl_eval - http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eval.html - to do the evaluation of expressions. Built-in functions are specially handled in this module. The combination of fun and a BIF just isn't implemented correctly in that module.

Comment: @chadwick Sort of, but not quite. When you use the syntax `fun foo/1` that means use the function `foo/1` which is in the current module. The current module for the shell is erl_eval. This applies even for BIFs like `hd/1`. If you want to call a function *not* in the current module then you have to explicitly give the module, in this case `erlang`. BIFs like `hd/1` are only special in this context because the compiler knows that they are in the module `erlang`.